# How to multiply two integers using two classes, Class one contains method int calculateMultiplication (int, int) and two contains main method?

Tags: java

I need help with this program. I need to multiply the two integers that are inputted by the user and then use the method **int calculateMultiplication (int, int)** to calculate the result. The first class contains the declaration of variables and the methods and the second class contains the main method with all the print. I don't know how to call the calculateMultiplication method to implement in my final print which gives **"The multiplication of *first user input (I got)* and *second user input (I got)* is *result (I don't have)***.

```
public class JavaApplication19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first int number: ");
    int num1 = input.nextInt();
    Two Num1 = new Two();
    Num1.setN1 (num1);
    int numOne = Num1.getN1();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the second int number: ");
    int num2 = input.nextInt();
    Two Num2 = new Two();
    Num2.setN2 (num2);
    int numTwo = Num2.getN2();  
    }
}  
    
This is the part I need help on: (this is just what i have so far)

    System.out.println("The multiplication of " + numOne + " and " + numTwo + " is" + product + "." );
    Two Result = new Two();
    int result = Result.calculateMultiplication(num1, num2);

class Two {
 
    private int result;
    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    
    public int getN1(){
        return n1;
    }
    
    public void setN1(int _n1){
        n1 = _n1;
    }
    
    public int getN2(){
        return n2;
    }        
    
    public void setN2(int _n2){
        n2 = _n2;
    }
    
    
    public int calculateMultiplication(int n1, int n2){
        int answer = this.n1 * this.n2;
        return result;
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Make the calculateMultiplication method static. public static int calculateMultiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with instance variables and method parameters.

The two class could be written a bit differently:

```
public class Two {
    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    private int result;
    public void setN1(int n1) {
        this.n1 = n1;
    }
    public void setN2(int n2) {
        this.n2 = n2;
    }
    public void multiply() {
        this.result = this.n1 * this.n2;
    }
    public int getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

It has two private `int` instance variables, `n1` and `n2`.

```
int num1 = 10; // for example
int num2 = 20; // for example

Two two = new Two();
two.setN1(num1);
two.setN2(num2);
two.multiply();
int result = two.getResult();
```

From here you can do whatever you need with the values.

Comment: The last line "int result = two.getResult();" isn't working when I put "result" in the print line.

Comment: `System.out.println("The multiplication of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is" + result + "." );`

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote but when I write it, it says variable result cannot be found. I put two.calculateMultiplication(); then under int result = two.getResult();. (I change multiply to calculateMultiplication).

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel the answer was useful, consider upvoting or marking as accepted if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first int number: ");
        Two num = new Two();

        int num1 = in.nextInt();
        num.setN1(num1);

        System.out.print("Enter the second int number: ");
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        num.setN2(num2);

        System.out.println("Multiplication: " + num.calculateMultiplication());
    }
}

public class Two {

    private int n1;
    private int n2;

    public int getN1(){
        return n1;
    }

    public void setN1(int n1){
        this.n1 = n1;
    }

    public int getN2(){
        return n2;
    }

    public void setN2(int n2){
        this.n2 = n2;
    }


    public int calculateMultiplication(){
        return this.n1 * this.n2;
    }

}
```